# Cannot find module '/dist/main' when using docker multi-stage builds

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

Here is the Dockerfile that I am using to build my nestjs project:

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY protos ./protos/
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

FROM node:14-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules/
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist/
COPY --from=builder /app/protos ./protos/
COPY --from=builder /app/tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/tsconfig.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/prisma ./prisma/
EXPOSE 5273
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

.dockerignore:

```
.vscode/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
dist/
graphql/
test/
```

The container can not work, and I get the :

```
Cannot find module '/dist/main'
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you run the container and check if the files are correct? You are copying the files to ./dist are you sure that the WORKDIR is /?

Answer (score 6):

the main.js file in dist is located on /dist/src/main.js

Comment: Where to update this in the Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 4):

Solved: I need to do COPY . . then RUN npm run build.

```
COPY . .    
RUN npm run build
```